# S3/ delete a file with delete mark in order to get the original one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file in S3 with [versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html).

I delete the file, and now it creates a new version with delete mark.

In order to restore it, I want to delete the version with the delete mark.

The problem is that I using node.js and I can't use the AWS console. is there any API to do that?

Meaning API that support deleting a file with delete mark (or delete file with specific version, but then I need another API to know the version with the delete mark).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "delete market" (using the ID of the Delete Market). You can do this with the deleteObject function (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#deleteObject-property) specifying the `Bucket`, `Key`, and `VersionId`